# Attach an existing Elastic Network Interface with Elastic IP to a new instance while auto scaling has been triggered

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, autoscaling, elastic-ip

I want to attach an existing ENI to a new EC2 instance whenever auto scaling is triggered using lambda. I have found an example on how to do it with a new ENI here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/attach-second-eni-auto-scaling/ but don't know how to do it with an existing one. I'll also be okay with a solution wherein a new ENI is created with an existing Elastic IP using Lambda.

Comment: - Do you only need a single instance?  If so you can just include the ENI in the launch template and the ASG will re-use it on each new instance. If you need a static outbound IP you could consider a NAT Gateway (although there is some cost associated with that).  If you need a static inbound IP you could consider a Network Load Balancer

Comment: @Shahad - There will be at the most 2 instances 1 of which will be triggered by the auto scaling rule. How will the launch configuration attach a new private IP if I attach an ENI to it?

Comment: You can't use a launch configuration.  You have to use a launch template and define a single ENI in it.  You have to have min/max/desired = 1 in the ASG and create it via the CLI specifying AZs instead of subnets.  All of the settings of this ENI (including its IP address) will be used on subsequent instances if this one has to get replaced in this ASG
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/create-launch-template.html